# How to import google contacts into Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, thunderbird, email, contacts

Is it possible to import / link my gmail contacts address book with the online accounts feature of Ubuntu 13.04?

It doesn't make sense that that functionality exists for twitter and facebook but not for gmail...

Google does off course make this functionality available as I used to use it in kmail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've previously used the Google Contacts add-on for Thunderbird. This creates a separate folder in your address book with your google contacts and seems to work fairly well.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want as it does not interact via the online accounts feature.